# How can I determine whether or not a wordpress menu item is active?

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, menuitem, objectid

I'm using Wordpress to create menus and I'm trying to use the `object_id` to determine whether or not the menu item is active. The problem is that when I set the `menu-item-object-id` manually, it is overridden by it's own `ID`.

I have a function that creates the menu and then another that adds menu items to each menu:

```
function create_menu($menu) {

    foreach($item in $key => $menu['items']) {
        create_menu_item($item, $key, $menu['id']);
    }
}

function create_menu_item($item, $position, $menuID) {

    // i'll use a dynamic value for the object id, but not even hard coding it works
    $args = [
        'menu-item-position' => $position,
        'menu-item-title' =>  (isset($item['title'])) ? $item['title'] : null,
        'menu-item-classes' => (isset($item['classes'])) ? $item['classes'] : null,
        'menu-item-url' => (isset($item['url'])) ? $item['url'] : null,
        'menu-item-status' => (isset($item['status'])) ? $item['status'] : 'publish',
        'menu-item-parent-id' => (isset($item['parent'])) ? $item['parent'] : 0,
        'menu-item-object-id' => '5'
    ];

    wp_update_nav_menu_item($menuID, 0, $args);
}
```

Everything seems to be working as expected except for the `menu-item-object-id` property! I manually set it be object's ID but when I use `wp_get_nav_menu_items()` the `$post->object_id` is always the same as it's own ID, `$post->ID`.

```
function get_menu() {

    global $post;

    $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_items('primary');

    foreach($menu as $item) {

        // $item->object_id should now be '5' but instead it is equal to $item->ID so I am unable to check if it's active

        if($item->object_id == $post->ID) {
            // item is active
        }
    }

    return $menu;
}
```

Why is my `menu-item-object-id` property being overwritten?

Comment: Adding `$args['menu-item-type'] = 'page';` allows me to set the `menu-item-object-id` property correctly, but now the `menu-item-url` property is an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

It's really not intuitive or documented anywhere, but the solution was to set `post_type` as the `menu-item-type` and `menu-item-object` to `page`.

```
$args['menu-item-type'] = 'post_type';
$args['menu-item-object'] = 'page';
$args['menu-item-object-id'] = $page->ID;
```

Once you have those properties set, setting `menu-item-url` becomes unnecessary. Wordpress will automatically set the url using the page permalink.